# Handling Complex Voting System

Tags: users, voting

I'm wireframing a semi-complex voting model for an award website where the user can vote for a nominee.  Where it is complex is there are multiple divisions for the groups of nominees. It's laid out with a photo of each nominee, and my idea was to pop a modal / lightbox for the voting and full information / bio of the nominee.

The voter is allowed to vote for one nominee, per division, per day, so the thought is if I keep them on a single page so a user to pick and choose a winner in their respective decision.

A second idea is to have the user choose all of their nominees and enter in a final submit.

I think I'd prefer the first, but any insight into one over the other?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot / wireframe you can include in your question?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how your site is structured but my approach would be something like this:

[image]

The approach on the right allows you to nominate the same person to several different categories while the option at the bottom restricts nominations to only a single category.

The full size image is stored [here](http://postimage.org/image/e35l9gmdx/)

Comment: Perfect, that should work with the checkboxes.